# Subscript out of bounds error in R package Tax4Fun

Tags: r

I used SILVAngs ( a tool for analyzing microbial community) for analyzing the soil bacterial community structure. Additionally, I wanted to predict the metabolic potential of the bacterial community and thus using the Tax4Fun R package.
On that note, when I used the command as instructed in the tutorial (http://tax4fun.gobics.de/RPackage/Readme_Tax4Fun.pdf) for Tax4fun for importing OTU predictions in R I get an error.

The full script I used is as follows:

```
library(Tax4Fun)
importSilvaNgsData(inputFiles ="npkvsnk---ssu---fingerprint----Total---sim_93---tax_silva---td_20.csv")
```

The error I am getting is :

> Error in data[[rlabp]] : subscript out of bounds

I tried to solve it but couldn't.

It would be appreciated if I can get some help.

The link to download the input file is : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wxkREdl-lAeMA4ne35vn-_deYUdmLwf4

Comment: I don't know but I have bad feeling with this weird file name. \

Comment: If you are using a function that is not on CRAN or BioC repositories, then you should give full instruction for locating and installing.